# Receive answer from a delegate method on main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have the following scenario: I want to call a method on background thread many times, but the returned value comes from a delegate method, which I think is called on main thread. How can I handle this on background thread ?

```
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
for (int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++) {
    NSBlockOperation *blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self.routingService calculateRoute:self.routeSettings];
    }];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:blockOperation];
}

//Delegate method
- (void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didFinishRouteCalculationWithInfo:(SKRouteInformation *)routeInformation {

    //Here I want to process routeInformation
}
```

Please help me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this inside you delegate method

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //add your processing code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //add your background processing code here

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//add processing on main thread
});
```